# Delete previous version of an excel file

Tags: excel-2016

How can I delete the older versions of an excel file so that other users won't be able to restore a previous version?

I tried to copy it on desktop and then back to shared folder but it seems it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you restore it to the newest previous version the other previous versions disappears.